# Which vaccinations do I need to travel South America extensively?

Tags: health, south-america, vaccinations

other than covid19

Last time I was there I had some weird/unusual acne(or rash? idk) on me even though I was in urban areas

Comment: If you are concerned, you should seek the advice of a qualified medical professional (try searching "travel medicine" and the name of your home city). You can also refer to [the CDC's travelers' health page](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/) or your country's equivalent.

Comment: Without a medical diagnosis what you experienced could have been anything, including an allergic reaction to something.

Answer (score 3):

The US Centers for Disease Control maintain an online source for [health-related travel advice](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/list). Each country's listing includes suggested and applicable vaccines and medicines.